# Pandas UDF that creates SparseVectors

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to define a pandas udf that allows to create `SparseVectors` from a column of dictionaries. Below is an example

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.ml.linalg import SparseVector, VectorUDT
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# create example data
dff = spark.createDataFrame([Row(features=Row(indices=[1,2], size=10, values = [11,12])),
                             Row(features=Row(indices=[3,4], size=10, values = [13,14])),
                             Row(features=Row(indices=[5,6,7], size=10, values = [15,16,17]))
                            ])

print(dff.printSchema())

# access values in the struct
dff.withColumn('sparse', col('features')['size'])
```

I can access individual key value pairs in the features column, so I use rdd.map to create `SparseVectors`.

```py
# create sparse vectors using rdd.map works fine
dff.rdd.map(lambda x: SparseVector(x.features['size'],
                                   x.features['indices'],
                                   x.features['values'])).collect()
```

I would like to do the same without using rdd. I tried using `.withColumn`.

```
# trying using withColumn and SparseVector
dff.withColumn('sparse', SparseVector(col('features')['size'],
                                      col('features')['indices'],
                                      col('features')['values']))
```

but get below error.

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Column'
```

I tried defining `udf`s below.

```
# create sparse vector using column of dictionaries and udfs
#@udf
#def create_s_vector(x):
#    return SparseVector(x['size'],x['indices'],x['values'])

# not sure whats the proper returnType
@pandas_udf(VectorUDT(), PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def create_s_vector(x_iter):
    for x in x_iter:
        yield SparseVector(x['size'],x['indices'],x['values'])

# try using udf
dff.withColumn('sparse', create_s_vector(col('features')))
```

With the above code I get the error that returnType type is not supported. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if this is just a misunderstanding, but when you use `yield` the return type is `PandasUDFType.SCALAR_ITER`. An iterator pandas UDF doesn't seem to be neccessary, as you can simply initiate your `create_s_vector` udf as pandasudf with `create_s_vector_pdudf = pandas_udf(create_s_vector, VectorUDT())` and apply it with `dff.withColumn('bla', create_s_vector_pdudf('features')).show()`.

Comment: @cronoik apparently `pandas_udf` does not support `VectorUDT()` return type.

Comment: Sorry I haven't tested that before. I think you have to stick with ordinary udf's for now.